# FTP - Client downloads WAR file instead if showing it as a website

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, filezilla

Okay so my problem is that I need to deploy my website from eclipse to an online server which is provided by my university. I've been handled a guide, which suggested that I converted my entire project into a WAR file. The WAR file is placed on my desktop and that particular path is also applied in my Filezilla setup. 
The problem is, when I try to run the code through filezilla with the following URL

ftp://Kristian1709tomcat@Kristian1709.tomcat.student.hum.au.dk/webapps/b-exam-ba-newssite.war -

My browser starts downloading the WAR file instead of showing it as a website.

My instructions from my teacher is as followed:

The Host
Kristian1709.tomcat.student.hum.au.dk

Username: Kristian1709@tomcat

Password: *******

Any sort of help will be very welcomed as I have to handle in the entire project for my finally exame tomorrow.

In advance thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, this site is for questions & answers post in order to share knowledge, please visit the help center in order to review how to ask a question in this site, tnks.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you sure you have been using an apllication server to host and run this war, not only a web or ftp server? Which type of application server?

Comment: I have been using the Tomcat server. Could it perhaps be something about its settings?

Comment: It is deployed, active? path/to/file.war/path/to/jsp?

Answer (score 0):

FTP stands for File Transfer Protocol, in my experience War files are to be run inside an application server, such as glassfish or tomcat server, and viewed through a browser, not a FTP client

Make sure its hosted within an application server and a change of url should fix your problem.

I have about 4 war files deployed on a glassfish server, that's independent of http and ftp.

go here in your browser `Kristian1709.tomcat.student.hum.au.dk`
And login/deploy

Comment: When I try to change it the page won't be found. 

The following is the error message: 

Not Found

The requested URL /webapps/b-exam-ba-newssite/news.jsp was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at student.hum.au.dk Port 80

Any suggestions?